# Implement Docker isolation for multiple users

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I’ve been asked to configure a ubuntu 18.04 server with docker for multiple users.

Purpose:
We have multiple testers who write test cases. But our laptops aren’t fast enough to build the project and run tescases in docker environment.
We already have a jenkins server.But we need to build/test our code BEFORE push to git.

I’ve been given a high end ubuntu 18.04 server.
I have to configure the server where all our testers can run/debug our testcases on isolated environments.

When testers push there changes to remote servers project should build and run on isolated environments. Multiple users can work on same project but one testers builds must NOT affect another one.

I already installed Docker and tried with only changing docker-compose.yml and adding different networks (using multiple accounts of course). But it was very painful.

I need to have multiple selenoid servers(for different users),different allure reports with docker , Need the ability to build and run tests using our docker-compose files and need the ability to run the actual project on different ports so we can go through the system while writing test cases.

Is it possible to configure an environment without changing project docker-compose.yml ?
Whats the approach I should take ?

Comment: don't attempt to build the project locally. Create builds from branches in CI, push those builds to a docker hub and then your testers can simply pull those images. Your docker-compose can then stop building and simply reference pre-built images to pull. Your are making life hard for yourself. Try out gitlab CI and see the difference a simple configuration can make to your workflow, it comes with free minutes. You'll find that the cost of that is much less then all the effort you are putting in to try and make this option "work">

Comment: @PaulCollingwood the main issue we have is we are unable to build/run docker images on our laptops. That's what we are tying to achieve by configuring one High End server rather than buying new laptops for every tester.

Comment: Thats not what @PaulCollingwood said. Instead of buying new laptops, set up an automatic CI/CD. Gitlab allows this in a easy way (also in the free plan).  Gitlab can automatic create environments from new commits (via kubernetes) and the testers just use them.

Comment: @akop we already have a jenkins server. But we need to test our code BEFORE push to git. Thats the issue we are currently facing.

Comment: Why? When everybody push to it own branch (google for "git flow") and using "merge requets", then is there no reason to keep code local until it is tested.

Comment: @akop we are testers who writes test cases using protractor framework. Are you suggesting us to push our code without testing ?

Comment: Yes. If you're using gitlab, then you can configure it to execute the protector-testcases. While gitlab testing your stuff, you are able to do other things. At our company, this setup works very well.

Comment: But for sure, the new developed test-cases should be implemented and tested locally first (so you can debug it). If you need environments for each tester (and the software is too big to started local) I suggest that a) you setup a big instance on your server which can be used by everyone (when the software can handle multiple users) or b) you set up instances for each tester - this is easy with k8s.

Comment: @akop Thats exactly what I'm trying to do. We need environments for each tester so we can test/debug our code. We did get a high end server. I'm trying to configure for all testers. That's the whole issue.

Comment: Ah, then I (and some others as I see) misunderstood you. Maybe you can edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Docker in Docker ([`docker:dind`](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) image) to run multiple instances of Docker daemon on the same host, and have each tester use a different `DOCKER_HOST` to run their Compose stack. Each app instance will be deployed on a separate Docker daemon and isolated without requiring any change in `docker-compose.yml`.

Docker in Docker can be used to run a Docker daemon from another Docker daemon. (Docker daemon is the process actually managing your container when using `docker`). See [Docker architecture](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#docker-architecture) and [DinD original blogpost](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/) for details.

---

## Example: run 2 Docker daemons exposing the app port

Let's Consider 2 testers with this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: 3
services:
  app:
    image: my/app:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

1. Run 2 instances of Docker Daemon exposing Daemon port **and any port that will be exposed by Docker Compose** (see below why)

```
# Run docker dind and map port 23751 on localhost
# Expose Daemon 8080 on 8081 (port that will be used by Tester1)
# privileged is required to run dind (see dind-rootless exists but is experimental) 
# DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="" is to deploy an unsecure Daemon
# it's easier to use but should only be used for testing/dev purposes
docker run -d \
  -p 23751:2375 \
  -p 8081:8080 \
  --privileged \
  --name dockerd-tester1 \
  -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="" 
  docker:dind

# Second Daemon using port 23752
docker run -d \
  -p 23752:2375 \
  -p 8082:8080 \
  --privileged \
  --name dockerd-tester2 \
  -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="" 
  docker:dind
```

2. Each tester can run their own stack on their Docker daemon by setting `DOCKER_HOST` env var:

```
# Tester 1 shell
# use dockerd-tester1 daemon on port 23751
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:23751

# run our stack
docker-compose up -d
```

Same for Tester 2 on `dockerd-tester2` port:

```
# Tester 2 shell
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:23752
docker-compose up -d
```

3. Interacting with Tester 1 and 2's stacks

> Need the ability to build and run tests using our docker-compose files and need the ability to run the actual project on different ports

The exposed ports for each testers **will be exposed on the Docker daemon host** and reachable via `http://$DOCKER_HOST:$APP_PORT` instead of `localhost:$APP_PORT` (that's why we also exposed app port on each Daemon).

Considering our `docker-compose.yml`, testers will be able to access application such as:

```
# Tester 1
# port 8081 is linked to port 8080 of Docker daemon running our app container
# itself redirect on port 8080
# in short: 8081 -> 8080 -> 80
curl localhost:8081

# Tester 2
# 8082 -> 8080 -> 80
curl localhost:8082
```

Our deployment will look like this

[image]

---

## Alternative without exposing ports, using Docker daemon IP directly

Similar to the first example, you can also interact with the deployed app by using Docker daemon IP directly:

```
# Run daemon without exposing ports
docker run -d \
  --privileged \
  --name dockerd-tester1 \
  -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="" 
  docker:dind

# Retrieve daemon IP
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' dockerd-tester1
# output like 172.17.0.2

# use it!
export DOCKER_HOST=172.17.0.2
docker-compose up -d

# our app port are exposed on Daemon
curl 172.17.0.2:8080
```

We contacted directly our Daemon via its IP instead of exposing its port on localhost.

---

You can even define your Docker daemons with static IPs in a `docker-compose.yml` such as:

```
version: "3"

services:
  dockerd-tester1:
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    networks:
      dind-net:
        # static IP to set as DOCKER_HOST
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6

  # same for dockerd-tester2
  # ...

networks:
  dind-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

And then

```
export DOCKER_HOST=10.5.0.6
# ...
```

---

Notes:

- This may have some performance impact depending on the machine on which Daemons are deployed
- You can use `dind-rootless` instead of `dind` to avoid using `--privileged` flags
- It's better to avoid `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""` for security reasons, see [`TLS` instruction on `docker` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) for detailed usage of TLS

Answer (score 1):

The OP has already an CI/CD-system running. The question is: How can testers wrote new testcases on a own enviroment which is not running on the local maschine.

I suggest that you setup a k8s (kubernetes) instance on your new "high-end"-server. The installation of [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) is very easy and enough when you has only one server (aka node).

With k8s you can control your docker-containers (or with the correct verb "orchestrate").
You can do one of these things next:

1. Wrote a script for the test-laptops, so they can start new environments. You can use the `$USER`-variable for the correct naming. Be aware that the testers may have access to k8s now.
2. My favorite: Don't create enviroments for users, create them for merge requets. They are not bound to users and can be created by your version-control-system (e.g. gitlab). The testers can open an MR, your server setup a new enviroment and the tester is ready to go. And your testers have no access to k8s.
3. Not recommended, but possible: Create enviroments manually for each tester.